# Completely Automatic Time Tracking for Windows 10

Tags: windows, logging, time, tracking

I've read some of the answers to similar question here but not found exactly what I want.

I want to know how much time I spend working with different programs during the day, with zero setup, naming of projects etc.

Obviously I often have multiple windows open, but I want the time spent with focus on each one tracked.

So for example at the end of the day I can see I spent 3 hours on Chrome (web-page breakdown a bonus), 4 hours in PyCharm and 120 mins in MS Word.

Like I say, I want zero manual configuration and it must work when I'm not online.

Any suggestions please?

Maybe I can even get this info from Windows logs with some filter applied?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a third-party solution for this.

The only application I know of that does this accurately, reliably and completely automatically is [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/).

The free version does almost everything but in order to see certain details, it requires you to upgrade to the $6/month paid version. The difference between the free and paid offerings is the difference between knowing that you spent 10 hours in MS Word this week, and actually knowing how much time you spent working on each named document, or knowing that you spent 5 hours using Google Chrome, versus knowing how much time you spent on each site in Chrome.

Probably the biggest downside is that it's SaaS. That means that all of your logged time data is saved in your RescueTime account which is hosted on US servers; however, it does work.

You can opt out of allowing tech support to see your data for troubleshooting with a checkbox in your account but, at the end of the day, you're still trusting all this collected metadata with the company that provides the software.

The application has some nice design features, like if it doesn't detect any keyboard or mouse input for 5 minutes, it subtracts 5 minutes from the last recorded activity then stops timing, so if you forget to lock your workstation (which stops timing immediately) when you walk away from your desk, it won't affect the accuracy of your metrics if you're gone for more than five minutes.

You can also easily delete irrelevant time entries from the logs with the click of a mouse, as well as tell it to always ignore certain applications to reduce noise.

It's a good product but it does insist on logging all applications by default, with you having to opt out of each application that you don't want to appear in your logs. When I used it, my ignore list had dozens of applications! Things like Windows Update and various Control Panel applets and parts of Windows all count as separate "applications" and if they have focus, they're in your logs by default. Any time you touch something, it appears in your logs but, as it learns what you don't care about, you can dial the noise all the way down.

I just wish it had an "opt-in" mode where you could just tell it the handful of programs that you *do* want it to log and ignore everything else by default instead!